# Oracle DB - Java Reference to uninitialized collection for a particular batch

Tags: java, spring, oracle, plsql

I have a java object which looks like this

```
Class A
{
  private String name;
  private List<B> bList;
}
```

I also have Oracle custom objects defined for these java objects.

```
create type T_B as object
                         (
                            myNumber  number,
                            message   varchar2(4000)
                         );

create type T_B_LIST  as table of T_B;

create type T_A as object
                         (
                           name varchar2(4000),
                           b    T_B_LIST
                         );

create type T_A_LIST  as table of T_A;
```

Now I have made 10 lists of A (`List<A>`) where each list contains 20 elements  and trying to insert them into the DB using a procedure. So basically I have 10 batches and total 200 elements.

```
 procedure add(a  in T_A_LIST)
 begin
   for i in 1..a.last loop
     insert into sometable values a(i).name ; 
   end loop;
 end
```

The issue is that some of the batches get insereted successfully, but somewhere 
around the 6th batch the pl/sql is failing with the following error.

```
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
```

I am using the Java/Spring ***SQLData*** class and ***java.sql.Struct*** and ***java.sql.Array*** objects to do the Java persistent layer.

I have tried different options like   insert the entire elements (200) in a single batch, but it still failing with same error.

```
public class A  implements SQLData{
    private  String name;

    private List<B> bList;
    private Array bArray;
    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {

        return  "T_A";
    }
    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(name);
        stream.writeArray(bArray);
    }

    // setters and getters
}


public class B implements SQLData {

    private Long myNumber;
    private String message;

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return "T_B";

    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeLong(myNumber);
        stream.writeString(message);

    }

}

// And the DAO logic
class Test
{
    List<B> bList; // A List of B objects
    List<A> aList;  // A list of A objects

    Array array = dbUtil.getOracleArray("T_B_LIST",
            bList.toArray());
    A a = new A(); 
    a.setBArray(array);
    aList.add(a);

    Array aArray = dbUtil.getOracleArray("T_A_LIST",
            aList.toArray());

    // DeclareParameter
    // call plsql procedure using SimpleJdbcCall giving the aArray as argument.


}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted any Java/Spring code so I am addressing why the error occurs from the Oracle side only.

**[TL;DR]** The error occurs when you pass a `NULL` value or a collection that has not been initialized. Either make sure you always pass a non-`NULL` initialized collection or use a `TABLE` expression.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_a_list( a  in T_A_LIST )
AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..a.last LOOP
     INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ( a(i).name ); 
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**: Passing an initialized collection:

```
BEGIN
  add_a_list(
    T_A_LIST(
      T_A( 'one',   NULL ),
      T_A( 'two',   T_B_LIST() ),
      T_A( 'three', T_B_LIST( T_B( 3.1, 'message 3.1' ) ) ),
      T_A( 'four',  T_B_LIST( T_B( 4.1, 'message 4.1' ), T_B( 4.2, 'message 4.2' ) ) )
    )
  );
END;
/
```

This works as expected as the collection has been initialized.

```
SELECT * FROM sometable;
```

Outputs:

```
| NAME  |
| :---- |
| one   |
| two   |
| three |
| four  |
```

**Query 2**: Passing a `NULL` value:

```
BEGIN
  add_a_list( NULL );
END;
/
```

Raises the exception:

```
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_UMPWUWIBMKJJGKGIRJGH.ADD_A_LIST", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

As the procedure reaches the `FOR` loop and tries to find the `a.last` value where `a` is `NULL` and raises an exception.

**Query 3**: Passing an uninitialized collection:

```
DECLARE
  value T_A_LIST;
BEGIN
  add_a_list( value );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_UMPWUWIBMKJJGKGIRJGH.ADD_A_LIST", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

As the procedure reaches the `FOR` loop and tries to find the `a.last` value where `a` is an uninitialized collection and raises an exception.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e44e4a63ff06ef97879d1aabcd50b52)*

**Oracle Setup - Modified**:

Use a `TABLE()` expression:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_a_list( a  in T_A_LIST )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO sometable ( name )
  SELECT name
  FROM   TABLE( a );
END;
/
```

Re-running queries 2 & 3 with the modified procedure runs without exceptions and does not insert any rows.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure the issue is because of its null. When I try to insert all my 200 entries chunk by chunk (where each chunk contains 10 objects) it finishes successfully.  But When I do it as a whole ( where T_A_LIST contains 200 objects) it's failing with the  Reference to uninitialized collection error.   I have added the java/spring part to the question, please have a look.